# "I have to..." vs. "I'm going to have to..." in context

Tags: difference

Can you please tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *I have to...* and *I'm going to hav*e to in the context below.

> Tomorrow I'm going home, so **I have to** wake up early to catch the bus.
>
> Tomorrow I'm going home, so **I'm going to have to** wake up early to catch the bus.

Answer (score 1):

The first is "I am *presently* obliged to wake up early tomorrow"

The second is "In the *future* I will be obliged to wake up early."

In the present example, there's really no difference.  But in some cases there may be a reason to prefer one over the other.